# How do I extract multiple character strings from one line using R

Tags: regex, r, text, readlines

I would like to extract multiple character strings from one line.

suppose I have the following text line (taken with the 'readLines' function form a website):

```
line <- "abc:city1-street1-long1-lat1,ldjad;skj//abc:city2-street2-long2-lat2,ldjad;skj//abc:city3-street3-long3-lat3,ldjad;skj//abc:city3-street3-long3-lat3,ldjad;skj//"
```

I would like to extract the following to separate lines:

```
[1] city1-street1-long1-lat1
[2] city2-street2-long2-lat2
[3] city3-street3-long3-lat3
[4] city4-street4-long4-lat4
```

I hope someone can give me a hint how to perform this task.

Answer (score 6):

`regmatches` to the rescue:

```
regmatches(line,gregexpr("city\\d+-street\\d+-long\\d+-lat\\d+",line))
#[[1]]
#[1] "city1-street1-long1-lat1"
#[2] "city2-street2-long2-lat2"
#[3] "city3-street3-long3-lat3"
#[4] "city3-street3-long3-lat3"
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution with the [stringi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(line, "(?<=:).+?(?=,)")[[1]]
## [1] "city1-street1-long1-lat1" "city2-street2-long2-lat2" "city3-street3-long3-lat3" "city3-street3-long3-lat3"
```

And with the [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(line, perl("(?<=:).+?(?=,)"))[[1]]
## [1] "city1-street1-long1-lat1" "city2-street2-long2-lat2" "city3-street3-long3-lat3" "city3-street3-long3-lat3"
```

In both cases we are using regular expressions.
Here, we are matching all the characters (non-greedily, i.e. with `.+?`)
which occur between `:` and `,`. `(?<=:)` means a positive look-behind: `:` will be matched, but not included in the result. On the other hand, `(?=,)` is a positive look-ahead: `,` must be matched but will not appear in the output.

Some benchmarks:

```
lines <- stri_dup(line, 250) # duplicate line 250 times
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
   stri_extract_all_regex(lines, "(?<=:).+?(?=,)")[[1]],
   str_extract_all(lines, perl("(?<=:).+?(?=,)"))[[1]],
   regmatches(lines, gregexpr("city\\d+-street\\d+-long\\d+-lat\\d+", lines)),
   lapply(unlist(strsplit(lines,',')),
       function(x)unlist(strsplit(x,':'))[2]),
   lapply(strsplit(lines,'//'),
        function(x)
          sub('.*:(.*),.*','\\1',x))
)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                            expr         min         lq     median             uq        max neval
## gagolews-stri_extract_all_regex    4.722515   4.811009   4.835948       4.883854   6.080912   100
##        gagolews-str_extract_all  103.514964 103.824223 104.387175     106.246773 117.279208   100
##          thelatemail-regmatches   36.049106  36.172549  36.342945      36.967325  47.399339   100
##                  agstudy-lapply   21.152761  21.500726  21.792979      22.809145  37.273120   100
##                 agstudy-lapply2    8.763783   8.854666   8.930955       9.128782  10.302468   100
```

As you see, the `stringi`-based solution is the fastest.

Comment: You might add the `strapply` function from the gsubfn package as another option.

Comment: @gagolews Are you the author of `stringi` package? good auto-promotion :)

Comment: I didn't know it will be so fast ;)

Comment: I never understood lookahead/behind regex until your explanation. Simple, but I was clearly overthinking it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option without using regular expression:

```
unlist(lapply(unlist(strsplit(line,',')),function(x)unlist(strsplit(x,':'))[2]))

"city1-street1-long1-lat1" 
"city2-street2-long2-lat2" 
"city3-street3-long3-lat3"
"city3-street3-long3-lat3"
 NA
```

### EDIT better solution

Using conbination of `strssplit` and `sub`. No need to set the exact complicated structure but just using **grouping** feature:

```
lapply(strsplit(line,'//'),function(x) sub('.*:(.*),.*','\\1',x))
[[1]]
[1] "city1-street1-long1-lat1" 
    "city2-street2-long2-lat2" 
    "city3-street3-long3-lat3" 
    "city3-street3-long3-lat3"
```

Answer (score 3):

For something simple like this, base `R` handles this just fine.

```
matches <- regmatches(line, gregexpr('(?<=:).*?(?=,)', line, perl=T))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. With my simplified example this works very well. However in the actual situation I need to extract all strings that are between '{\"name\":\' and '\"}'. I hope you (or someone else) can advise how to perform this task.

Comment: @user3638423 Can you provide an example input line?

Comment: It is a very long line (that why I simplified the example). To get the data you can run the following code:
www_SB <- readLines('http://www.schoonenberg.nl/winkels/')
line <- www_SB[300]

Comment: Ok so for example, `{"name":"Schoonenberg Hoorcomfort","url":"\/winkels\/schoonenberg-hoorcomfort-aalsmeer-zijdstraat-17-a","longitude":4.7467513,"latitude":52.2691185,"features":[],"id":"392858746"}` what part do you want out of that?

Comment: Thanks for you reply and your time. The part I want to extract is:
Schoonenberg Hoorcomfort","url":"\/winkels\/schoonenberg-hoorcomfort-aalsmeer-zijdstraat-17-a‌​","longitude":4.7467513,"latitude":52.2691185

Comment: `(?<="name":).*?(?=,"features")`