# How to check the pattern that starts with 1 and end with 2?

Tags: r, regex, string

The sequence will be something like:

```
"4122222222222281222222211111212"
```

The result I want is :

```
"1222222222222"

"12222222"

"12"

"12"
```

You can see that there can be arbitrary numbers of '2' within the pattern.

Is there any way to find such pattern in R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is to use the [pattern](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/finiteautomata/Section07/sect07_19.html#:%7E:text=The%20character%20%2B%20in%20a%20regular,is%20called%20a%20Kleene%20plus%20.) `"12+"`.

> The character `+` in a regular expression means "match the preceding character one or more times"

You can do this with the `stringr` library using the [`str_extract_all()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html) function:

```r
x  <- "4122222222222281222222211111212"
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "12+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "1222222222222" "12222222"      "12"            "12"
```

Alternatively in base R you can use [`regmatches()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/regmatches):

```r
m  <- gregexpr("12+", x)
regmatches(x, m)
# [[1]]
# [1] "1222222222222" "12222222"      "12"            "12"
```

Both of these approaches are vectorised and return a list. This is useful as if `x` is e.g. a data frame column the output will be a list of `length(x)`, where each element is a character vector containing all matches. However, if `x` is a vector of length `1`, you may wish to wrap the result in `unlist()` to return a vector. With the `stringr` approach you can also do:

```r
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "12+", simplify = TRUE) 
#      [,1]            [,2]       [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "1222222222222" "12222222" "12" "12"
```

This will return a character matrix, which in this case has one row. However, this may not be the desired result if your input has length `> 1`, as different numbers of matches will lead to a character array with `""` entries (rather than `NA`):

```r
x  <- c("4122222222222281222222211111212", "135", "123")
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "12+", simplify = TRUE) 
#      [,1]            [,2]       [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "1222222222222" "12222222" "12" "12"
# [2,] ""              ""         ""   ""  
# [3,] "12"            ""         ""   ""
```

For more about `stringr` functions and regular expression match characters in general, see RStudio's helpful `stringr` [cheat sheet](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf).

You could also use `stri_extract_all_regex(x, "12+")`, which `stringr::str_extract_all()` is a wrapper around.

#### Benchmarks

`stringr` is much faster than `regmatches()`. There are some [historical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665109/how-do-i-extract-multiple-character-strings-from-one-line-using-r) [benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773737/r-fastest-way-to-extract-all-substrings-contained-between-two-substrings) showing that [`stringi`](https://stringi.gagolewski.com/index.html) is faster than `stringr`. However, since `v1.0.0` of `stringr`, many of its functions are a wrapper around `stringi` functions and there is not much difference in performance between the two packages. Here are the results of this regex with vectors ranging from length `1` to `1e6` rows:

[image]

`stringi` appears to be slightly faster at with very short vectors but the actual time difference is tiny (nanoseconds). With longer vectors, we don't see much relative difference. Interestingly, the performance cost of simplifying into a matrix is not very high relative to the cost of creating the regex, even when the data is quite large.

##### Benchmarking code

```r
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

results <- bench::press(
    n_strings = 10^(0:6),
    pattern = "12+",
    {
        x <- stri_rand_strings(n = n_strings, length = 20, pattern = "[1-5]")
        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 10,
            check = FALSE,
            str_extract_all = {
                str_extract_all(x, pattern)
            },
            str_extract_all_simplify = {
                str_extract_all(x, pattern, simplify = TRUE)
            },
            stringi = {
                stri_extract_all_regex(x, pattern)
            },
            base = {
                regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))
            }
        )
    }
)

# # A tibble: 28 × 11
#    expression               n_strings pattern      min   median   `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#    <bch:expr>                   <dbl> <chr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>       <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#  1 str_extract_all                  1 12+       20.4µs   22.5µs  36001.          264B    3.60   9999     1   277.74ms
#  2 str_extract_all_simplify         1 12+       21.5µs   22.7µs  36481.          264B    3.65   9999     1   274.09ms
#  3 stringi                          1 12+        6.3µs    6.6µs 125851.            0B    0     10000     0    79.46ms
#  4 base                             1 12+       24.3µs   27.2µs  28786.        8.09KB    5.76   9998     2   347.32ms
#  5 str_extract_all                 10 12+         25µs   28.8µs  22913.          264B    2.29   9999     1    436.4ms
#  6 str_extract_all_simplify        10 12+       26.4µs   27.9µs  30625.          472B    3.06   9999     1   326.49ms
#  7 stringi                         10 12+       10.4µs   10.8µs  72548.            0B    7.26   9999     1   137.83ms
#  8 base                            10 12+       72.4µs   84.1µs   8692.       80.94KB    8.72   3988     4    458.8ms
#  9 str_extract_all                100 12+       64.6µs   68.7µs  12231.        1.09KB    2.03   6039     1   493.75ms
# 10 str_extract_all_simplify       100 12+       69.8µs  75.55µs  10732.        3.48KB    2.02   5300     1   493.87ms
# 11 stringi                        100 12+       49.7µs   51.8µs  16697.          848B    0      8335     0   499.18ms
# 12 base                           100 12+      507.7µs 677.15µs   1201.      813.95KB   13.2     548     6   456.18ms
# 13 str_extract_all               1000 12+      487.4µs 546.45µs   1526.        8.12KB    2.02    756     1   495.26ms
# 14 str_extract_all_simplify      1000 12+      538.8µs  568.5µs   1610.       47.23KB    0       805     0   500.08ms
# 15 stringi                       1000 12+      469.1µs  558.1µs   1555.        7.86KB    2.01    772     1   496.62ms
# 16 base                          1000 12+       5.01ms   5.56ms    177.        7.95MB   20.2      70     8   395.96ms
# 17 str_extract_all              10000 12+       4.94ms   5.32ms    170.       78.43KB    0        85     0   500.24ms
# 18 str_extract_all_simplify     10000 12+       5.24ms    5.8ms    167.      390.98KB    1.98     84     1   503.92ms
# 19 stringi                      10000 12+       4.86ms   5.34ms    160.       78.17KB    2.00     80     1   500.44ms
# 20 base                         10000 12+      78.43ms  88.56ms     11.0      79.46MB   12.1      10    11   905.52ms
# 21 str_extract_all             100000 12+      53.45ms  57.39ms     16.8     781.55KB    1.68     10     1   595.49ms
# 22 str_extract_all_simplify    100000 12+      59.91ms   66.8ms     13.6       4.58MB    1.36     10     1   734.33ms
# 23 stringi                     100000 12+      52.52ms  53.85ms     18.3      781.3KB    0        10     0    545.4ms
# 24 base                        100000 12+      808.5ms 992.12ms      0.956    794.6MB   14.6      10   153     10.46s
# 25 str_extract_all            1000000 12+     533.78ms 627.43ms      1.16      7.63MB    0.116    10     1       8.6s
# 26 str_extract_all_simplify   1000000 12+     637.49ms 709.24ms      1.36     53.41MB    0.136    10     1      7.34s
# 27 stringi                    1000000 12+     537.19ms 600.58ms      1.64      7.63MB    0.164    10     1      6.09s
# 28 base                       1000000 12+          10s   11.74s      0.0857    7.76GB    3.03     10   353      1.95m


# Plot
library(ggplot2)
p  <- autoplot(results) +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_wrap(vars(n_strings), ncol = 1, labeller = "label_both")
```